# Query list types using CAML in CQWP query override?

Tags: caml-query, content-query-web-part

When you export a Content by Query web part and open it up there is the `<property name="QueryOverride" type="String" />` tag which allows you to put in your own CAML query to specify further filters and sort by's.

I know that you can, in this property as well, query the Content Types, but  is it also possible to query for List Types if I want to query 4 different List Types in 1 CQWP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think specifying lists in CAML query in `QueryOverride` property is possible. The list is specified in Source property of CQWP.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CAML query into the QueryOverride, I've done it and it works flawlessly to help filter results more appropriately. You cannot however specify a list type to pull from, only list fields are available.